# Flatten nested object/array using lodash

Tags: javascript, reactjs, lodash

Is it possible to flatten this collections using lodash and concatenate the path strings? I tried to but can only reach second level, I want to flatten it regardless the depth as long as there's a pageRouter array inside the object

```
{
    component: () => React.createElement('div', undefined, 'Parent Page'),
    exact: true,
    pageTitle: 'Parent',
    path: '/parent',
    pageRoute: [
      {
        component: () => React.createElement('div', undefined, 'Child Page'),
        exact: true,
        pageTitle: 'Child',
        path: '/child',
        pageRoute: [
          {
            component: () =>
              React.createElement('div', undefined, 'Grandchild Page'),
            exact: true,
            pageTitle: 'GrandChild',
            path: '/grandchild',
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
```

to this?

```
 [
    {
      component: () => React.createElement('div', undefined, 'Parent Page'),
      exact: true,
      pageTitle: 'Parent',
      path: '/parent',
    },
    {
      component: () => React.createElement('div', undefined, 'Child Page'),
      exact: true,
      pageTitle: 'Child',
      path: '/parent/child',
    },
    {
      component: () => React.createElement('div', undefined, 'Grandchild Page'),
      exact: true,
      pageTitle: 'GrandChild',
      path: 'parent/child/grandchild',
    },
  ],
```

attempted code

```
const = routeList = _.flatMapDeep(publicRoutes, (x) => {
   if (x.pageRoute) {
      return [x, { ...x.pageRoute, path: x.path + _.head(x.pageRoute)?.path }];
     } else return x;
   });
```

Comment: Did you try `flatten` or `flattenDeep`?

Comment: Could you post your attempted code?

Comment: ```_.flatMapDeep(publicRoutes, (x) => {
   if (x.pageRoute) {
      return [x, { ...x.pageRoute, path: x.path + _.head(x.pageRoute)?.path }];
     } else return x;
   })```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need for `lodash`. Since this is a nested structure, it seems like a good opportunity for a recursive function:

```js
const components = [
  {
    component: () => React.createElement('div', undefined, 'Parent Page'),
    exact: true,
    pageTitle: 'Parent',
    path: '/parent',
    pageRoute: [
      {
        component: () => React.createElement('div', undefined, 'Child Page'),
        exact: true,
        pageTitle: 'Child',
        path: '/child',
        pageRoute: [
          {
            component: () =>
              React.createElement('div', undefined, 'Grandchild Page'),
            exact: true,
            pageTitle: 'GrandChild',
            path: '/grandchild',
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  }
];

const flattenedComponents = [...flattenComponents(components, '')];

console.log(flattenedComponents);

function* flattenComponents(nestedComponents, pathPrefix) {
  for (const { pageRoute: routes, path, ...component } of nestedComponents) {
    const newPath = `${pathPrefix}${path}`;
    yield { ...component, path: newPath };
    if (routes) {
      yield* flattenComponents(routes, newPath);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Wow this is great! I haven't thought of a function generator, would it make difference using a simple loop?

Comment: Simple loop is also ok; I just find generators elegant.

Comment: I'm getting ```flattenComponents' implicitly has return type 'any' because it does not have a return type annotation and is referenced directly or indirectly in one of its return expressions.``` this error as I use typescript, ```function* flattenComponents(nestedComponents:PageRoute[], pathPrefix: string = '')``` still not used to generator so I don't know where to infer the return type

Comment: You can type the return value as `Iterable<Foo>` where `Foo` has the structure of each component object.